# Install mathjax locally, but get fonts from the CDN?

Tags: fonts, mathjax

I have a mathjax installation with customized configuration (used through Sphinx) and need to store it on my server. The server's connection is not lightning-fast, so I would like to offload the largest portion of the data trasfers (math fonts) to the mathjax CDN. Is such split configuration supported or possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Sphinx, but for a plain HTML file, you would include

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Register.LoadHook("[MathJax]/jax/output/HTML-CSS/config.js",function () {
  MathJax.OutputJax["HTML-CSS"].webfontDir =
     "http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/fonts/HTML-CSS";
});
</script>
```

somewhere *before* the script that loads `MathJax.js` itself.  You will have to figure out how to get that into the configuration used by Sphinx.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).